# Spring Framework. Удаление и редактирование других пользователей админом

Tags: java, spring, service

Предполагается, что в приложении есть 2 роли: админ и пользователь.
Когда админ удаляет пользователя, он удаляется из базы, но его сессия остается открытой и он спокойно может посещать страницы пока не попробует снова залогиниться. Также и с данными пользователя, если админ поменяет роль пользователя, то она не обновится, пока он не перелогиниться. Как обновить данные пользователя не только в базе, но и в приложении?

Код удаления пользователя:

```
@GetMapping("/users/delete")
    public String adminUsersDelete(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user,
                                   @RequestParam("id") int id) {
        User userId = userService.getById(id);
        if (userId == null || userId.isAdmin())
            return "redirect:/admin/users";

        try {
            userService.deleteById(id);
            //todo delete session
        } catch (Exception ignored) {}
        if (user.getId() == id) {
            return "redirect:/logout";
        }
        return "redirect:/admin/users";
    }
```

Код обновления роли:

```
@GetMapping("/users/do_admin")
    public String adminUsersDoAdmin(@RequestParam("id") int id) {
        User userEdit = userService.getById(id);
        if (userEdit == null)
            return "redirect:/admin/users";

        userEdit.setRole(User.ROLE_ADMIN);
        userService.updateUser(userEdit);
        return "redirect:/admin/users";
    }
```

## Решение

```
@Service
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class MySessionService {

    private final SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

    @Autowired
    public MySessionService(SessionRegistry sessionRegistry) {
        this.sessionRegistry = sessionRegistry;
    }

    //Метод для удаления сессии любого пользователя
    public void expireUserSessions(String username) {
        for (Object principal : sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals()) {
            if (principal instanceof User) {
                User user = (User) principal;
                if (user.getEmail().equals(username)) {
                    for (SessionInformation information : sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(user, true)) {
                        information.expireNow();
                        killExpiredSessionForSure(information.getSessionId());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("End of expire");
    }

    public void killExpiredSessionForSure(String id) {
        try {
            HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            requestHeaders.add("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + id);
            HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity(null, requestHeaders);
            RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
            rt.exchange("http://localhost:8080", HttpMethod.GET,
                    requestEntity, String.class);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам может помочь вариант с протуханием сессии для удаляемого пользователя.

Посмотрите класс `SessionServise` из статьи  [Совершенствуем контроль сессий в Spring Security](https://habr.com/ru/post/346296/)

Comment: Ооо, поддерживаю, читал статью - огонь!

Comment: Сработало. Сначала скопировал код, но валилось на проверке `if (principal instanceof User)`, потом подправил и заменил преобразование с UserDetails на User, теперь все нормально удаляется. Спасибо.